# check if the first element of arrays inside an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
   int[][] myarray = 
  {             {1,0},
                {3,2},
                {0,1},
                {2,3}
        };
```

in HashMap i can use containsKey(i)or ,containsValue(i) to check if  i was used ;
is it possible to do the same with array ? i mean to check if in myarray i1 values z

i1 == the group of the first elements of each array inside `myarray`

in my example {1,3,0,2}

```
if  myarray[:,0] =  2  
    print("Numbers match")
```

Comment: The point of having a collections API in Java is to make it easier to work with collections of values than working with raw arrays. In your case, if you want to check if there is an element in the array that is a sub-array with a particular value at index 1, then you need to write a loop that check for exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understood your question, you want to check if the first element of every inner array is unique or not.

A simple solution is to loop through the outer array, access the first element of the inner array, and do the comparison with the new value.

Edit: create a small method `alreadyPresent()` that returns a boolean value after searching.

```
if (aleadyPresent(newValue)){
    print("Value already present")
}
```